# Can ask for strides of k subsequent items from a pandas series?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset (in an pandas series) organized like so :

```
s: AAAAABBBBBCCCCCAAAAABBBBBCCCCCAAAAABBBBBCCCCC....
```

n(=3) streams of data organized in k(=5) sample chunks.

Is there an *efficient* way to use strides or somesuch in pandas to unpack the data into n series?

```
a = # All the A's
b = # All the B'a
c = # All the C's
```

ideally, with their original indexes.
Strides only seem setup to pick every n-th, not picking k every m-th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(list('AAAAABBBBBCCCCCAAAAABBBBBCCCCCAAAAABBBBBCCCCC'))
```

Reshape the underlying array and slice

```
s.values.reshape(-1, 5)[::3].ravel()

['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']


s.values.reshape(-1, 5)[1::3].ravel()

['B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']


s.values.reshape(-1, 5)[2::3].ravel()

['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C']
```

You can take it a step further with

```
v = s.values
v.reshape(-1, 3, 5).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(3, -1)

[['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
 ['B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']
 ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C']]
```

Comment: What does -1 mean?  It seems like magic number.  What does 5 mean? It seems like it means groups are 5 long before they start repeating. What does 3 mean? It seems like it is a mystery to me, maybe 3 unique letters in list.

Comment: When reshaping, you're allowed to use `-1` once.  It evaluates to be whatever is left over.  So if I have an array with shape `(3, 4)` and I reshape it with `(2, -1)` that evaluates to `(2, 6)`.

Comment: What do [::3] and [1::3] mean in this particular example?

Comment: Python slicing syntax can express a starting point, end point, and step size expressed as `start:end:step`.  The values have defaults when things are left out but `[::3]` assumes the default start of `0`, the default end of `None` and a step size of `3`.  This will start with the first item and every third one after that. `[1::3]` starts with the second and every third after that.